# Hoot determine GTK3 memory leaks on OS X

Tags: udp, gtk3

I've written a small single-line oriented UDP based display service to support raspberry pi projects I frequently work on, where it would be nice to see the results of sensor data being captured.  This is a rewrite of that program using GTK3 V3.18.9, and GLIB2 V2.46.2.   I'm developing on OSX El Capitan

It seems to double in real memory size every 30 minutes or so based on traffic; so I'm presuming I have a memory leak somewhere.  But for the life of me I can't see where in the code it could possible be.  Val grind did not initially work for me, so I've got some studying to do to resolve what ever issue that is.

Meanwhile I was hoping that different eyes might be able to suggest a coding cause for a traffic based (at least I think so) memory leak.  Here is the program and test client.

It starts up using about 10MB of real memory, then jumps when it has received 64 total messages to 14MB, than slowly grows from there.   At 64 message, I start deleting the 65th message off the end of the list, presuming I should be saving memory; as this program might run for weeks.

Here is the code for the test client and the display service: 
https://gist.github.com/skoona/c1218919cf393c98af474a4bf868009f

Comment: compile both program with (adjusted): gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -O3 -Wall -o gtkDisplayService gtkDisplayService.c

Comment: Discovered that the code is fine, its the environment.  The referenced code work fine on Linux (Ubuntu, Centos, Raspbian).  The leaking memory issue is only present on OS X.